# running a script from another script

Tags: macos, bash, command

I have a script located at /tmp/"My Batch Script Files"/Processing

How would I run this from the home directory /tmp/ in another script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is executable:

```
"/tmp/My Batch Script Files/Processing" arg1 arg2 ...
```

If it is not exectuable, either make it executable or:

```
bash "/tmp/My Batch Script Files/Processing" arg1 arg2 ...
```

You can place the double quotes around the whole path name as I did, or around the component containing the spaces, or almost any other location you choose in between.  With just two double quotes, this as close together as you can place them:

```
/tmp/My" Batch Script "Files/Processing arg1 arg2 ...
```

or use backslashes if you prefer (I don't recommend them, though):

```
/tmp/My\ Batch\ Script\ Files/Processing arg1 arg2 ...
```

On the whole, though, I'd go with the first suggestion, or use:

```
proc_script="/tmp/My Batch Script Files/Processing"

"$proc_script" arg1 arg2 ...
```

This is particularly attractive if you generate the file name while the outer script is running.